# mariadb REGEXP_INSTR returns 0 or 1 when using brackets

Tags: regex, mariadb, backreference

MariaDB Documentation says about REGEXP_INSTR:
Returns the position of the first occurrence of the regular expression pattern in the string subject, or 0 if pattern was not found.

My task is (simplified): finding o followed by a double consonant

```
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('a_kollision', 'o([lm])\\1'); # -> expected 4 got 1
```

It returns 1 but I would have expected 4 as the position of oll

Doing the same with replace works:

```
# replace works as expected
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('a_kollision', 'o([lm])\\1', '???'); # -> a_k???ision -- OK
```

It seems that the trouble starts when using brackets in REGEXP_INSTR:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('a_kollision', 'oll', '???'); # -> a_k???ision  -- OK
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('a_kollision', '(oll)', '???'); # -> a_k???ision  -- OK
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('a_kollision', 'oll'); # -> 4  -- OK
SELECT REGEXP_INSTR('a_kollision', '(oll)'); # -> 1  -- why?
```

If there is no match REGEXP_INSTR returns 0 as expected.

Used db: 10.1.13

Also checked with latest stable version: 10.2.6
No difference.

Comment: It is most certainly a bug in the PCRE implementation in MariaDB `regexp_instr` or a hidden feature (though I doubt about the latter).

Comment: File a bug with mariadb.com

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I reported it at mariadb.com

Comment: MariaDB team reacted very fast. Bugfix will be available in 10.1.25 and 10.2.7.
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12942